# Make swf video fitting 100% page width

Tags: html, flash, width

Im testing (at school) and trying to achieve the same page as [this](http://www.capellahotels.com/newyork/) I want to know which size should I make the swf file (to look like the above link) and make it fit 100% width of the screen?

thanks

Sarah

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<object></object>` in a `div`. Set `height` and `width` of `div` as you want and assign `100%` to `height` and `width` of the object.